# Как обратится к колонке таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть запрос:
`SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 u.id FROM [dbo].[TABLE] tab (nolock) LEFT JOIN BD.dbo.users u ON u.id=tab.menID WHERE tab.ID = t.mID) c_id FROM dbo.[Tables] t (nolock) WHERE c_id=1`

Выходит ошибка `Invalid column name 'c_id'.`
Как можно обратится к колонке `c_id`, чтобы прописать условие? Спасибо.

Comment: Обернуть в один большой внешний `select * from (ваш запрос) where c_id=1`. Но получится очень плохо. потому что сначала будут выбраны все записи из Tables, потом для каждой из них будет выполнен подзапрос и наконец будет применено условие которое отфильтрует записи. Стоит поискать кардинально другой подход к задаче

Comment: И кстати top 1 без order by выглядит очень странно, вам действительно нужна 1 _произвольная_ запись, т.е. не минимальная, не максимальная, а именно первая попавшаяся (какая попадется предсказать невозможно, в зависимости от того как на диске лежат и от фазы луны еще немного)

Comment: Да, какой странный запрос. Может опишите задачу? А там уже может и совсем по другому делать надо?

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь, задача решена. Решение крылось в join. Спасибо :).